# Is it possible that the union of two undecidable languages is decidable?

Tags: formal-languages, turing-machines, undecidability

I'm trying to find two languages, $L_1, L_2 \in RE \setminus R$, such that $L_1 \cup L_2 \in R$.

I have already proved that if $L_1\cap L_2 \in R$ **and** $L_1 \cup L_2 \in R$, such $L_1, L_2$ don't exist (because otherwise we'll be able to construct a Turing Machine $M_1$ which will decide $L_1$, for instance).

However, I cannot prove that it's impossible in the case $L_1\cap L_2 \in RE \setminus R$, and I can't find such languages.

Comment: Your observation about the intersection is incorrect. Take $L_1,L_2\in RE\setminus R$ such that $L_1\cap L_2=\emptyset$, then $L_1\cap L_2\in R$.

Comment: @Shaull - just to be clear, I proved that there aren't any $L_1, L_2 \in RE \backslash R$ s.t. $L_1 \cap L_2 \in R$ and $L_1 \cup L_2 \in R$.

Comment: Ah, I see. That's indeed correct. Perhaps consider editing the post to clarify that.

Comment: Your observation shows that the same problem, but with *disjoint* union has no solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Take $L_1=\{0\cdot x:x\in \Sigma^*\}\cup \{1\cdot x: x\in A_{TM}\}$ and $L_2=\{1\cdot x:x\in \Sigma^*\}\cup \{0\cdot x: x\in A_{TM}\}$. Clearly both languages are in $RE\setminus R$.

However, their union contains $\{0\cdot x\}\cup \{1\cdot x\}=\Sigma^*\setminus\{\epsilon\}$, and therefore equals $\Sigma^*\setminus \{\epsilon\}$, and is therefore decidable.

Comment: Strictly speaking it's $\Sigma^{\ast}$ without the empty word.

Comment: why it is cleary in $ RE \setminus R $ why its not in $ R $ ?

Comment: @mayacohen - because $A_{TM}$ easily reduces to each of them. E.g., for $L_1$ the reduction is $f(x)=1\cdot x$.

Comment: what is the notation of Atm means? @Shaull and can I also what to know if the intersection is in R ? is it the empty lang?

Comment: @mayacohen - $A_{TM}=\{\langle M,w \rangle:\ M\text{ accepts }w\}$. Just a canonical $RE\setminus R$ language. The intersection $L_1\cap L_2$ is not in $R$ (think why!)